# Installed Docker-Compose 2.0 but for some reason it is using an a 1.0 version

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-machine, apt

I attempted to update Docker-Compose in Linux using the instructions on the Docker Website.  I get the following when I type `sudo apt install docker-compose-plugin`

```
After this operation, 25.7 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Selecting previously unselected package docker-compose-plugin.
(Reading database ... 139053 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../docker-compose-plugin_2.10.2~ubuntu-jammy_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking docker-compose-plugin (2.10.2~ubuntu-jammy) ...
Setting up docker-compose-plugin (2.10.2~ubuntu-jammy) ...
```

When I try to type `docker compose` it does not work.  When I type `docker-compose version` I see:

```
docker-compose version 1.29.2, build unknown
docker-py version: 5.0.3
CPython version: 3.6.9
```

What step am I missing?  I want to be able to use a 2.0 version with the `docker compose` type entry.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

For some reason, Docker was installed as a Snap Packaging rather than the suggested method on the Docker website to use apt.  I could not find a way to snap install or update docker-compose on its own with Snap.  I just uninstall docker with `sudo snap remove docker`, then reinstalled using the most up to date directions on Docker's site, using apt.